# Populating future dates in oracle table

Tags: oracle, join

I have attached tables, product and date.
Lets say my product table has data till yesterday i.e 05/31/2018
am trying to populate season table where I could do the calculation till 5/31/2018 where value =  (value on same day last year/previous day last year) with Ch(a) and P(pen), however the data set was till 5/31/2018. my aim is to get data/calculation for 06/1/2018 till 12/31/2018 as well. how do i get the data for these future dates as I have the data to calculate these future dates in prod table.

appreciate if you can help.
Thank you!

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Are you trying to generate dates between 6/1 and 12/31?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a series of dates using CONNECT BY subquery like this one:

```
SELECT Start_date + level - 1 as my_date
FROM (
  SELECT date '2018-01-01' as Start_date FROM dual 
)
CONNECT BY Start_date + level - 1 <= date '2018-01-05'
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/072359/1

```
|              MY_DATE |
|----------------------|
| 2018-01-01T00:00:00Z |
| 2018-01-02T00:00:00Z |
| 2018-01-03T00:00:00Z |
| 2018-01-04T00:00:00Z |
| 2018-01-05T00:00:00Z |
```